# what does this Linux script mean?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, script

I read a Linux script with the following statements. I cannot understand the first line, anybody can explain it to me?

what is number '1', ':' and '~'?

if I want to add another two locations there, how to do it?

```
location=${1:-'/home/project1'}

find ${location} -type f -name "ParameterConfig.properties" -exec sed -i 's/;K50;/;K41;/g' {} +
```

Comment: `$1` or `${1}` expands to the first positional parameter (aka argument). `${1:-defaultvalue}` expands to the first positional parameter if it is set and nonempty, otherwise the specified defaultvalue. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02 . Note this won't work if the the 'location' (pathname) contains any IFS character(s), or any glob character(s) if they match or if not and failglob or nullglob.

Comment: *[ "$1" ] || set -- '/home/project1'; find "$@" -type f ...* you can run the script with two (or more) other locations (given as arguments) and run *find* straight on positional parameters (where you have set *project1* as default when no arguments given)